# What is a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

This question was marked and closed as a duplicate: [Ubuntu Server 20.04.4 LTS is unable to detect Wi-Fi adapter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1421048/ubuntu-server-20-04-4-lts-is-unable-to-detect-wi-fi-adapter)

The closure pointed to this as the duplicate: [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Now, I happen to agree that the answer there is quite good, however, it doesn’t answer the original question, unable to detect wifi adapter; it is a request to post additional diagnostic details.

Please see: https://askubuntu.com/help/duplicates where it clearly says: “In general, the original question must have an answer…”

In my opinion, a request for additional information is not an answer. The additional information, if provided, may or may not lead to an answer, but is not an answer on its face.

What shall we do when a question is closed by a purported duplicate that is not actually an answer but a request for more information?

Shall we vote to reopen and note our conclusion or something else?

Comment: You have suggested a different Duplicate in the original question to this one: https://askubuntu.com/q/1263111/57576?

Comment: This is an alternative of closing as unclear. "My Wi-Fi doesn't work" isn't answerable. Either OP adds information, or it is closed as a dupe.

Comment: @Pilot6 please don't use it that way. Closing as unclear actually tells the user what the problem with their question is. Closing as a duplicate of something that isn't actually a duplicate since it doesn't provide an answer is not helping the OP learn. I would instead suggest closing as unclear and leaving a comment linking the OP to the question about getting wi-fi info, so they know what they need to add to make it answerable.

Comment: @terdon I used to act exactly this way. But I reviewing close votes I meet some of these and I agreed, but I also thought that it is not the best idea. I'll vote as unclear after a comment as before.

Comment: @Pilot6 Reopened so this can move ahead...

Comment: I have proposed an answer to the original question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A request for more information is not an answer and therefore not a duplicate. It does not provide a working solution to the asked question. Please see: https://askubuntu.com/help/duplicates

> In general, the original question must have an answer…

It is preferable to vote to close as unclear and make a comment; something like:

> As stated, your question is unclear as it lacks the necessary details
> to propose an answer. Please start here:
> [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)
> Please edit your question to include the result of the wireless info
> report.

Comment: I have asked at least at least one user not to use that for a duplicate