# Is there any way to block a question to be used as a duplicate

Tags: feature-request

There are too many times this is used as a duplicate, [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)
The wireless script is just a tool to help find the answer, it is not an answer to many questions.

My reason for asking this is [D-Link DWA-182 Rev C Ubuntu 23.10 is not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1492029/d-link-dwa-182-rev-c-ubuntu-23-10-is-not-working) amoung many others flagged as duplicate by a few users

I see this has another similar question at [What is a duplicate?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/20082/what-is-a-duplicate) but it needs to be fixed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We already implemented tag warnings to make people provide that information: [Tag Warning Is Now Live for "Wireless"](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/14270/158442). If people still don't provide it, then I'm OK with using duplicate close votes as a way to ask OP for that info instead. It has two advantages:

- The post should end up being closed anyway due to lack of clarity, so this kills two birds with one stone by both casting a CV and having that CV inform OP in a very clear way what to do next.
- The UI presented for duplicates makes it much more noticeable than for any other close vote. Users are asked directly at the top of the post about the duplicate, so it's hard to ignore.

---

In the specific example given, it did have the unfortunate defect that OP themselves agreed to close it, but I think there's no harm done. They've added the information so if nominated for reopening, there will be no disagreement.

Comment: The question has now been reopened, by the way.

Comment: I see your point of killing two birds with one stone, but I would very much prefer the question being closed as unclear and the dupe target added as a comment requesting additional information, so that we would not give the wrong impression that it's okay to close unclear questions as duplicates.